# Does ActiveJob with Sidekiq adapter have performance issue against pure Sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I see [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#performance) in Sidekiq official wiki that ActiveJob would be much slower.

But it is mentioned on Mar 2018, based on Rails 4.2 and Sidekiq 5.1.1 according to this [issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3782), and the latest would be Rails 6 and Sidekiq 6.

Is it still this case that pure Sidekiq worker would be much suggested than ActiveJob with Sidekiq adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared a simple benchmark: https://github.com/mpan-wework/sidekiq-benchmark/actions?query=workflow%3ARSpec

```
CreateUserJob
  behaves like Benchmark Job
"CreateUserJob-0, 1601366451612"
"CreateUserJob-last, 500, 1601366532766"
    runs for 501 times

PureJob
  behaves like Benchmark Job
"PureJob-0, 1601366532791"
"PureJob-last, 500, 1601366542691"
    runs for 501 times

CreateUserWorker
  behaves like Benchmark Worker
"CreateUserWorker-0, 1601366542695"
"CreateUserWorker-last, 500, 1601366621057"
    runs for 501 times

PureWorker
  behaves like Benchmark Worker
"PureWorker-0, 1601366621072"
"PureWorker-last, 500, 1601366630103"
    runs for 501 times

Finished in 2 minutes 58.5 seconds (files took 1.72 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures
```

The benchmark result is run over github actions with one postgres container as database and one redis container as cache.

`Pure` job or worker only contains in-memory commands, `CreateUser` job or worker will create 100 users through SQL.

`0` represents the timestamp of the first job/worker to run; when every job/worker finishes, it will write its id and end time to cache, so `last` represents the last job/worker.

For each type of job/worker, 501 items are enqueued.

From the data collected, `PureJob` takes 9.900 seconds while `PureWorker` takes 9.031 seconds; `CreateUserJob` takes 81.154 seconds while `CreateUserWorker` takes 78.362 seconds. Sidekiq worker is faster than ActiveJob with Sidekiq adapter, but not as much as stated.

I have not yet tested on kubernetes cluster with multiple rails and sidekiq pods, but I guess the difference would not be significant.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJob is an adapter layer on top of Sidekiq::Worker, it will always add overhead. That said, how much overhead is version-, application- and usecase-specific so only you can measure your own system to determine the kind of overhead you are seeing.

> Benchmarks show that Active Job is 2-20x times slower pushing jobs to Redis and has ~3x the processing overhead (with Rails 5.1.4 and Sidekiq 5.1.1).

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#performance

Comment: Could you please go into more details? What are the benchmarks now? As far as I find, this sentence was added in 2018. I believe there are so many changes in Ruby, Rails and Sidekiq so it does not make sense to conclude on the basis of 2018 result. (Even maybe the author forgot to update this part?) Under Ruby 2.6, Rails 6 and Sidekiq 6, what are the benchmark results? Are they still 2-20x and 3x as you stated? Better with environment like throughput, concurrency, cloud instance parameters

Comment: I don't have the benchmark code anymore. It's an opportunity for you to build your own and publish a blog post on the results!